# Android app: How do change the battery percentage?

Tags: android

I'd like to access the battery details so I'll be able to change it.
For example, display 80% battery instead of 50%.

How do I access that in my code?

Thanks in advance!
Dvir

Comment: you want to do WHAT? what possible good reason could there be for doing that?

Comment: Here is a code sample that explains how to get battery information: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html

Comment: *Weird Question...*. But from what I can recollect is you want to change battery percentage in Android emulatot Check [this link for the same](http://prakash-satya.blogspot.in/2011/07/changing-battery-percentage-in-avd.html).. Check **@tostao** comment to retrive battery percent

Comment: I guess this is to take screenshots for display in Google Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private Handler handler = new Handler;

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryMenter code hereanager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
        Log.i(TAG, "level: " + level + "; scale: " + scale);
        int percent = (level*100)/scale;

        final String text = String.valueOf(percent) + "%";enter code here
        handler.post( new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
};
```